# Request Dialog- How to get the sender id

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I send a invite ,Below code is used to give you the request id. I'm the sender A. I send invite to b.I can get the request_id but how to get the A UID.

```
 //get the request ids from the query parameter
 $request_ids = explode(',', $_REQUEST['request_ids']);

 //build the full_request_id from request_id and user_id 
  function build_full_request_id($request_id, $user_id) {
  return $request_id . '_' . $user_id; 
 }

 //for each request_id, build the full_request_id and delete request  
 foreach ($request_ids as $request_id)
 {
 echo ("reqeust_id=".$request_id."<br>");
 $full_request_id = build_full_request_id($request_id, $user_id);  
 echo ("full_request_id=".$full_request_id."<br>");

try {
 $delete_success = $facebook->api("/$full_request_id",'DELETE');
 if ($delete_success) {
    echo "Successfully deleted " . $full_request_id;}
 else {
   echo "Delete failed".$full_request_id;}
}          
catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
echo "error";}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set it: `$user_id_A = $facebook->getUser();`

Here's some info about the getUser() method: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getUser/

Comment: :Setting a variable _a will not give me the a uid.

Comment: $facebook->getUser() gets the current logged in user. In your case that's user A (the user sending the request), right?

Comment: The method returns a uid. Call the method above your other code (for the request dialog) and store it in a different var than $user_id

Answer (score 1):

It's late but I thank this is your answer...[How to send a Facebook application request to retrieve data on accepting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13151253/how-to-send-a-facebook-application-request-to-retrieve-data-on-accepting)

```
if(isset($_GET['request_ids']))
{
    $request_ids = $_GET['request_ids'];
    $request_ids = explode(",", $request_ids);
    for( $i=0; $i < count($request_ids); $i++ )
    {
        $request_object = $facebook->api($request_ids[$i]);
        if(isset($request_object['data'])){
            $req_data = $request_object['data'];
            $i = 50 + count($request_ids);
        }
    }
}


FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
       redirect_uri: 'url',
       message: ' your message',
       data : '<?=$user_id?>'
    }, requestCallback);
```

Where `$req_data` will be the sender user id.