# How to send a Facebook application request to retrieve data on accepting?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Need to send a request for a Facebook application so that when the user accepts the request I need to retrieve the name of the person who sent it and the name of the person who accepted it. Can someone please share examples of the codr

Answer (score 2):

while sending invite you can add any data to track, let say you want to send `sender_name` so your send request function will be like:

```
FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests',
        message: "has invited you to the app",
        filters:['app_non_users'],
        data: sender_name
    }, function (response) {
    });
```

and when the receiver comes to your application clicking the request notification sent, then you can retrieve data and delete the request in php as below:

```
if(isset($_GET['request_ids']))
   {
       $request_ids = $_GET['request_ids'];
       $request_ids = explode(",", $request_ids);
       foreach($request_ids as $request_id)
            {
                 $request_object = $facebook->api($request_id);
                 if(isset($request_object['data'])) $req_data = $request_object['data'];//you can now use the sent $req_data your way
                 $full_request_id = $request_id."_".$current_user_fbid;
                 $facebook->api("$full_request_id","DELETE");
            }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you would be using a Database. When a user invites a friend the response of the request sent would contain response.request and response.to. Store this request_id alongwith user and users friend id (invited friends).

```
function inviteuser(){
    FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests',
        message: "Apllications message goes here",
        exclude_ids: [1, 2, 3],
        filters:['app_non_users'],
        data: "optional additional data you may pass for tracking"
    }, function (response) {
        if (response && response.to) {
        //callback function, will be called after user invites his friend, response object will contain list of all users invited
        //save response.to and response.request in database
        }
    });
}
```

When user accepts an invitation i.e. comes to your application canvas page by clicking on app request notification, Facebook sends comma separated ids in "request_ids" parameter. You can get this request ids and compare with your database to get required information.